# Why do i get Security sandbox voilation error even after adding crossdomain.xml?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I was getting this error earlier as

```
Security sandbox voilation: cannot load data from http://sample:8080/SignOut
```

What i got to know it to add a crossdomain.xml inside the `tomcat/webapps/ROOT/` folder.

But interesting thing is that, even after adding this am getting the same error. Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: how does your crossdomain.xml looks like... how do you load it ? please provide some code

Comment: I have added the contents of crossdomain.xml in the question. I think am not loading it anywhere..

Comment: can you try to use System.security.loadSecurityPolicy();

Comment: Where did you put the cross domain file?

Comment: can you access http://sample:8080/crossdomain.xml?